# Meaning of the very simple SPARQL query on LinkedGeoData endpoint?

Tags: sparql, ontology

I am a newbie to SPARQL. Though I have read some materials about RDF and SPARQL, I still cannot understand the meaning of the mysterious SPARQL query on [the LinkedGeoData SPARQL endpoint](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql)

```
Prefix lgdr:<http://linkedgeodata.org/triplify/> 
Prefix lgdo:<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/> 
Select * { ?s ?p ?o . }
Limit 1000
```

What does this oversimplified where condition `?s ?p ?o` mean?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any relationship between the title of your question and it's content.

Comment: The query you ask about will return 1,000 triples from the endpoint with no filter or condition applied i.e.{?s ?p ?o. } will match any triple.

Comment: @chrisis So it's just like a SQL query doing `SELECT s, p, o FROM <some_table> LIMIT 1000`?

Comment: Nearly, more like SELECT * FROM <some_table> as RDF data are triples you're not missing anything.

Comment: @chrisis Thanks! Would you mind to post your response as the answer? I will approve it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you ask about will return 1,000 triples from the endpoint with no filter or condition applied i.e. {?s ?p ?o. } will match any triple.
It's similar to SELECT * FROM aView in SQL if aView was a union of all, or most, of the tables in a SQL database.